# i18n-active_record - stack level too deep (SystemStackError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working with the `i18n-active_record gem` for translations in my project but I need to include an error handler for missing translations

I need to add a method called `call` to the module `I18n::Backend::ActiveRecord::Missing`, but I have this error `stack level too deep (SystemStackError)`

I am working on ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.12

This is my code:

```
module I18n
    module Backend
      class ActiveRecord
        module Missing
          def call(exception, locale, key, options)
            if exception.is_a?(I18n::MissingTranslation)
              self.store_default_translations(locale, key, options)
              # options[:rescue_format] == :html ? exception.html_message : exception.message
              ''
            elsif exception.is_a?(Exception)
              raise exception
            else
              throw :exception, exception
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

I18n::Backend::ActiveRecord.send(:include, I18n::Backend::ActiveRecord::Missing)
```

any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: how do you use this `call` method ?